# Create new certificate store in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, creation, certificate-store

I am trying to create a new certificate store in Windows programmatically using C/C++.

I started with this function - `CryptAcquireContext`, and wrote this piece of code:

```
#include<windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProvider;
    PCWSTR DefaultContainerName = L"MyStoreName";
    PCWSTR DefaultProviderName = MS_STRONG_PROV;
    DWORD DefaultProviderType = PROV_RSA_FULL;
    DWORD DefaultProviderFlags = CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET | CRYPT_SILENT | CRYPT_NEWKEYSET;

    printf("%d\n", CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProvider, DefaultContainerName, DefaultProviderName, DefaultProviderType, DefaultProviderFlags));

    return 0;
}
```

The container name and provider name values have been picked up from a design document that I am supposed to follow.

I dont know if this is the correct way to create stores, because after running this and opening the Certificate snap-in of MMC, I do not see the store of the given name. The program prints 1 on being run first time, and 0 from the second time onward.

Is this the correct way ? If yes, why don't I see the store in MMC ? If no, what is the correct way to create new certificate stores using C/C++ ?

Please feel free to point out any mistakes in the code.

Comment: "If the function succeeds, the function returns nonzero (TRUE).
If the function fails, it returns zero (FALSE). For extended error information, call `GetLastError`."
So what does GetLastError return?

Answer (score 1):

`CryptAcquireContext` can create a key container. A key container is not the same thing as a certificate store.

To create a certificate store use `CertRegisterPhysicalStore` or `CertRegisterSystemStore`.

Comment: Thank you. Also please check my answer. I stumbled onto it unexpectedly. Could you explain in brief the difference between a key container and a certificate store ?

Comment: Key containers contain keys, certificate stores store certificates... :-)     . . . . A certificate is a public key, together information about who owns the key, digitally signed by another key. A key container can hold public keys, private keys and symmetric secret keys. The job of the key container is to protect the private and secret keys. The job of the certificate store is to hold a searchable and organised list of certificates and make them easy to find and access. In that way they are opposites.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at one function in one of the codebases I was dealing with, I thought it was creating a store. So I wrote a small code snippet with that function, and voila - the store is getting created.

Function : [CertOpenStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Despite its name which signifies an opening of a store, it created the store I specified if it did not exist. Otherwise, it would have opened the existing store. (I do not find any documentation for this).

Here is my code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HCERTSTORE store = NULL;
    LPCSTR StoreProvider = CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM;
    DWORD Flags = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    PCWSTR StoreName = L"MyStore";

    store = CertOpenStore(StoreProvider, 0, NULL, Flags, (void *)StoreName);
    if(store == NULL)
        printf("Could not open store");

    return 0;
}
```

Checking certificate snap-in of MMC after running this code, I could see the store names 'Mystore' getting listed.

Ben's answer is also correct and I would say is preferable because the function deals specially with registering certificate stores.